# Undo in C, copy struct

Tags: c, copy, undo

I'm new to C and I'm trying to simulate an Undo functionality for a problem. I'm using generic vectors defined like this:

```
 typedef void* Element;

    typedef struct {
        Element* elems;
        int size;
        int capacity;
    } Vector;
```

For this, I created a function called "Copy" that should return me a copy of the vector I'm passing:

```
Vector* copyVector(Vector *v) {
    Vector* rez;
    rez = createVector();
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < getSize(v); i++) {
        Element el = getElem(v, i);
        add(rez, el);
    }
    return rez;
}
```

It works when I call it everytime to save the "before" vector... like when I try to apply an add or remove on my current vector, I call this copy function first on another vector called undoVec like this:

```
undoVec = copyVector(v);
```

I checked and it works but when I call my undo function... which should do the reverse of the code before:

```
v = copyVector(undoVec);
```

It's not working anymore. Doesn't do anything. It wont modify my vector v... which is really just a pointer I think

```
void undoVector(Vector *v, Vector *undoVec)
```

What am I doing wrong? why wont this functionality work? I can paste more code or give more info if required, thanks.

```
void add(Vector *v, Element elem) {
    if (v->size == v->capacity) {
        isFull(v);
    }
    v->elems[v->size] = elem;
    v->size++;
}

Element getElem(Vector *v, int pos) {
    return v->elems[pos];
}
```

Comment: A stack is more appropriate for undo functionality.

Comment: I only need to be able to apply the undo once for now and this was the way we were advised to take. Any idea why it's not working though?

Comment: Could you show us the `getElement` and `add` functions, too? Have you checked whether or not the value of `v` changes?

Comment: Are you assigning `v = copyVector(undoVec);` in the `undoVector` function? If so that will only change the value of the parameter inside `undoVector`, not the value of the what ever you called the function with.

Comment: I pasted the code for add and getElem. The parameters for undoVector are pointers to vectors so shouldn't they get modified? They do get modified in the rest of my functions so..

Comment: I checked what happens when I do v = copyVector(undoVec) and it empties my v. I just did a print inside the function and it says it's empty but if I call it outside... it's not empty, it's unmodified. I'm confused

Comment: @Melph7 Right, the parameter is a pointer to a vector... now re-read what TheDark said, because it applies no matter what the parameter is.

Answer (score 0):

Use a stack to implement because stack has a top.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on The Dark's comment:

> Are you assigning `v = copyVector(undoVec);` in the `undoVector` function?
>   If so that will only change the value of the parameter inside
>   `undoVector`, not the value of the what ever you called the function
>   with.

If you have

```
void undoVector(Vector *v, Vector *undoVec)
{
    v = copyVector(undoVec);
}
…
    undoVec = copyVector(v);
    …
    undoVector(v, undoVec);
```

the parameter `v` in `undoVector()` is a different object from `v` outside of `undoVector()`, it's just a copy that has initially the same value; thus, the `v = copyVector(undoVec)` only changes the value of the parameter `v` in `undoVector()`, but leaves untouched the independent `v` outside.

To achieve what you want, make it

```
void undoVector(Vector **v, Vector *undoVec)
{
    *v = copyVector(undoVec);
}
…
    undoVec = copyVector(v);
    …
    undoVector(&v, undoVec);
```

or - more similar to `copyVector()` and simple -

```
Vector *undoVector(Vector *undoVec)
{
    return copyVector(undoVec);
}
…
    undoVec = copyVector(v);
    …
    v = undoVector(undoVec);
```

or - most simple -

```
    undoVec = copyVector(v);
    …
    v = copyVector(undoVec);
```